# How to use .aggregate to get data from multiple collections, including sum values with Mongoose + NextJS

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to return the data from 2 Schemas. One of those contain the info of 'Players', and the other one contain the info of the 'Scores' by game for each 'Player.

**This is my 'Player' schema:**

```
import { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";

const PlayerSchema = new Schema({
    creator: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    },

    name: {
        type: String,
        require: [ true, 'Name is required!' ],
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: [ true, 'Email already exist!' ],
        required: [ true, 'Email is required!' ],
    }
});

const Player = models.Player || model( 'Player', PlayerSchema );

export default Player;
```

**This is my 'Score' schema:**
*(note this one also contain a subdocuments content)*

```
import { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";

const scoresToSave = new Schema({
    player: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Player',
    },
    score: { type: Number }
});

const ScoreSchema = new Schema({
    creator: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    },

    tournament: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Tournament',
    },

    date: {
        type: Date,
        require: [ true, 'Date is required!' ],
    },

    scores: [scoresToSave],
});

const Score = models.Score || model( 'Score', ScoreSchema );

export default Score;
```

**This is an example of the actual documents saved in the Collections.**

**Players:**

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"652f3470729e8d8a59b221dd"},
"creator":{"$oid":"652af415729e8d8a59b2202f"},
"name":"Player 1",
"email":"player1@email.com"
}

{
"_id":{"$oid":"652f36c9f6ad40c3aedf0cdf"},
"creator":{"$oid":"652af415729e8d8a59b2202f"},
"name":"Player 2",
"email":"player2@email.com"
}
```

**Scores**

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"65386103b5e6b094e0980f2a"},
"creator":{"$oid":"652af415729e8d8a59b2202f"},
"tournament":{"$oid":"652f2515729e8d8a59b221b6"},
"date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1698192000000"}},
"scores":[
  {
    "player":{"$oid":"652f3470729e8d8a59b221dd"},
    "score":{"$numberInt":"10"},
    "_id":{"$oid":"65386103b5e6b094e0980f2b"}
  },
  {
    "player":{"$oid":"652f36c9f6ad40c3aedf0cdf"},
    "score":{"$numberInt":"20"},
    "_id":{"$oid":"65386103b5e6b094e0980f2c"}
  }
]
}

{
"_id":{"$oid":"6538611bb5e6b094e0980f59"},
"creator":{"$oid":"652af415729e8d8a59b2202f"},
"tournament":{"$oid":"652f2515729e8d8a59b221b6"},
"date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1698192000000"}},
"scores":[
  {
    "player":{"$oid":"652f3470729e8d8a59b221dd"},
    "score":{"$numberInt":"11"},
    "_id":{"$oid":"6538611bb5e6b094e0980f5a"}
  },
  {
    "player":{"$oid":"652f36c9f6ad40c3aedf0cdf"},
    "score":{"$numberInt":"21"},
    "_id":{"$oid":"6538611bb5e6b094e0980f5b"}
  }
]
}
```

**This is the data structure that I want to create as response:**

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("652f3470729e8d8a59b221dd"),
    name: 'Player 1',
    email: 'player1@email.com',
    totalScore: 21
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6536f85cb5e6b094e09809f1"),
    name: 'Player 2',
    email: 'player2@email.com',
    totalScore: 41
  },
]
```

**My actual code to try to get that data structure is:**

```
import { connectToDB } from "@utils/database";
import Player from "@models/player";

export const GET = async ( req ) => {
    const resources = {
        "_id": "$_id",
        name: { "$first": "$name" },
        email: { "$first": "$email" },
        "totalScore": { "$sum": "scores.scores.score" },
    };

    try {
        await connectToDB();

        const players = await Player.aggregate([
            {
                $group: resources
            }, {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "Scores",
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "scores.player",
                    as: "score"
                }
            }
        ]);

        console.log('TRY: ', players);

        return new Response(
            JSON.stringify(players),
            {status: 200}
        );
    } catch (error) {
        return new Response(
            "Failed to fetch all players",
            {status: 500}
        );
    }
}
```

**This is what `console.log('TRY: ', players);` returns:**

```
TRY:  [
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("652f3470729e8d8a59b221dd"),
    name: 'Player 1',
    email: 'player1@email.com',
    totalScore: 0,
    score: []
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6536f85cb5e6b094e09809f1"),
    name: 'Player 2',
    email: 'player2@email.com',
    totalScore: 0,
    score: []
  },
]
```

May someone try to help me to understand what I'm missing there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to do your `aggregate` on the `scores` collection. Simply because that is where your `scores.score` fields is located so that is where you can perform the `$sum`. There could be more efficient ways but this query should return your desired results:

```js
const players = await Scores.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$scores"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$scores.player",
      totalScore: {
        $sum: "$scores.score"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "players",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "fromPlayers"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$fromPlayers",
              0
            ]
          },
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      fromPlayers: 0,
      creator: 0
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q0GxBje6PEx) for a working example.

**Explanation**:

1. `$unwind` : flatten the `scores` array so that we get one object per scores document. This obviously duplicates the documents but is easier to then group by player.
2. `$group` : group each object by player and `$sum` their scores.
3. `$lookup` : now join the `players` collection based on `_id`. But because `$lookup` returns an array, just assign to a new field called `fromPlayers`.
4. `$replaceRoot` : create a new root document by merging the `fromPlayers` array with the original document from previous pipeline stage.
5. `$project` : now remove that `fromPlayers` array and `creator` field from the ouput.

Comment: just exactly what I needed. I added { $sort: { "count": 1 } }, to return the data on the order that I want. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.